# Please suggest an alternative without ALL File Access in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-fileprovider, android-11

In my application, I am getting a base64 string data for PDF. I tried to open that directly within the application. But I don't find any solutions for this. So tried an alternative like , save that data as a pdf in the storage and open with an external PDF viewer application. And it works fine. But it requires All files access permission. Now while trying for play store release they are asking for reasons or alternative solutions for best practice.

Please see my implementation below and let me know if any alternative without using All files access permission.

Writing base64 string to a file :

```
String base64= dataPDFString;
            File file5 = null;
            try {
                File pdfDirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
                file5 = new File(pdfDirPath, "MyData" + ".pdf");
                 boolean value1 = true;
                if (!file5.exists()) {

                    value1 = file5.createNewFile();
                }
                if (!checkpermissions()) {

                    requestPermission();
                   }
                else
                {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file5);
                    outputStream.write(Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP));
                    outputStream.close();

                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        outputStream.close();
                    }

                    OpenFile(file5, base64);

                }
```

Then opening that PDF on external app as :

```
private void OpenFile(File contentUri, String base64) {
    Uri path;
    Intent intent = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
       
        path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".helper.ProviderClass", contentUri);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    else
    {
        path = Uri.fromFile(contentUri);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: They will only allow for all access files if you give solid reason for accessing all files. Alternative solution is download files in any standard directory like Download, Pictures, Music, Documents. As per your requirements make a your app folder in one od those directory and download your file in it.

Comment: Save to getExternalFilesDir() instead. No permissions needed. Use FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: @blackapps is it possible to open it in an external PDF viewer from getExternalFilesDir() without this persmission?

Comment: No permissions needed.

Comment: @blackapps can you suggest one example?

Comment: Just use getExternalFilesDir() instead of the one you use now. And.. no permissions needed.

Comment: @blackapps Tried that and but showing an error on pdf viewer as   open failed: EACCES(Permission denied)

Comment: [This Java example](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider) (and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.0/PdfProvider)) demonstrate using `ACTION_VIEW` and `FileProvider` to display a PDF. In my case, the PDF is copied out of assets, rather than being downloaded, but the principle is the same.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am getting PDF report as base64 from the server each time.

Comment: That's fine. You can write that to a file, just as I am copying the asset to a file.